# Spark Job Failed to Load Dynamic Configuration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lazy-evaluation, typesafe-config

I have a following settings.

```
application.conf
project {
   env = ${?PASSED_FROM_ENV}
}

Main.scala
object Main {
   val config = ConfigFactory.load()
   val env = config.getInt("project.env")

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      implicit val context = ....
      //Using the variable somewhere in the main
   }
}
```

I have a configuration which reads from environment.

```
export PASSED_FROM_ENV=10
```

It then initializes this configuration outside of main method. Code below does not work, I get class initialization exception. However when I change the val declaration to lazy, or move it inside the main, this works fine. In Spark job, is there some sort of initialization going on for dynamically passed down variables statically? I was wondering SparkContext initialization is required before we can read config from the environment?

Thanks!!